# "No module" after setting up jupyter kernel

Tags: python, tensorflow, import, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I installed tensorflow using the [official instructions](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/tensorflow/):

```
conda create -n tf-gpu tensorflow-gpu
```

If I activate the kernel, I can see tensorflow is installed.

```
conda activate tf-gpu
python3 -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__)'
```

It returns the following.

```
2022-03-24 01:21:50.006341: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
2.4.1
```

Now I want to have `tf-gpu` recognized as a kernel in jupyter notebook.

```
conda deactivate tf-gpu
python -m ipykernel install --user --name=tf-gpu
```

However, when I launch jupyter notebook

```
jupyter notebook
```

The created `tf-gpu` notebook does not work as expected.

```
import tensorflow
```

Returns the following error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

Why is the package not being recognized?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make a new kernel for this env and select the kernel from jupyter notebook as follows:

```
conda activate env_name
pip install ipykernel --user
python -m ipykernel install --user --name env_name --display-name env_name
```

Then open the notebook >> click on kernel >> change kernel >> select the kernel.

Let us know if the issue still persists. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Or you can also use `ipython kernel` instead of `ipykernel` after installation as shown below:

`ipython kernel install --user --name env_name --display-name env_name`