# No module named pandas error even though I have it installed and interpreter set (Dataspell, Jupyter notebook/lab))

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython, conda, dataspell

Package manager: conda

- Using virtual environment: base conda environment
- Errors found in the following IDEs: Dataspell, Jupyter notebook

*- No errors in the following IDE: vs code*

**error:**

```
import pandas as pd
```

```
no module named 'pandas'
```

First I'll go through the dataspell/jupyter notebook issue

## Dataspell/jupyter notebook

[image]

**Notice the executable**. It's not using the conda python exe.
**Notice the path**. Reaffirms that it's not seeing the anaconda directory.

But when I open the interpreter settings for this workspace,

[image]

## The kernelspec

Note: There's only one kernel spec directory
[image]

The file looks  like this

[image]

## It works in vscode

[image]

**Again Notice the executable and path. Both are using/seeing the anaconda python exe.**

So my question is this - Why isn't dataspell/jupyter notebook seeing anaconda as a path and using the base env? And how do I fix it?

Comment: Is it possible to create a kernel that uses the anaconda python executable?

Comment: Have you tried something along the lines of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71733561/8508004) to try what your last comment suggested?

Comment: It worked!! Thank you so much I was trying to find that command.

Answer (score 0):

The link in Wayne's comment worked. Just needed to create a new kernel by going into the virtual environment. https://stackoverflow.com/a/71733561/8508004 is the post that has the answer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Can you be a bit more explicit?